XMHD X Mail Hard Drive Files Recovery
I found some old xmhd files in my gmail and am looking to recover them.
For those who do know: XMail Hard Drive ("XMHD") was a service that connected to your Gmail account and allowed you to save files directly to it, like Google Drive. Due to Gmail's attachment limits, it would split larger files into 7mb xmhd files and attach them into emails that were sent to yourself.
This was in 2005. The site has been offline for a long time and the file format is proprietary.
How can I recover these files?

Can you find an old build of the Xmail software? I recall several products back then that offered this function, and used one or another of them myself. But I don't recall that particular name.

to my knowledge there was never any software available to the end user. xmhd was a beta website that accessed your gmail account.

It's possible this is just a package of some sort. Try opening it with 7zip? Or open it with a hex editor and inspect the headers.

7zip "cannot open". The hex was all gibberish to me. There is a 32 char string which looks like an md5 hash in the file name.
